# Database Structure for Application

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I'm building some relational database on MySQL and have some problem.
For example I have a table Client and Cources.
One client can visit multiple Cources.
How can be this stored in database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing this would actually be a many-to-many relationship, which you would model with three tables:

```
Client
 - ClientId (PK)
 - other fields

Cource
 - CourceId (PK)
 - other fields

ClientCourceVisit
 - ClientId (FK)
 - CourceId (FK)
 - other fields
```

Comment: Hum, do you mean FK instead of PK on the ClientCourceVisit table ? I think that one shouldn't have any primary key... right ?